# How does event scheduler in MySQL work?

Tags: mysql

This is my MySql Script but then my a_site_questions table didn`t update every 1:01 minute.

```
Create EVENT get_hall_of_fame ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1:01' MINUTE_SECOND DO 

UPDATE a_site_questions set `status` = 0 where !date_publish = now()
```

Comment: Is the event scheduler enabled? Check with this command: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event%'`  ... If you find that it is OFF, you can set it this way: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler="ON"`

Comment: It`s already fixed sir thank you.

Comment: So was it enabled, or was there some other issue? (for others that might cross this question)